# switch button's image on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code

```
- (IBAction)switchSetting:(UIButton *)sender {
    if([sender.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_on"]]){
        [sender setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_off"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }else{
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        //[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_on"] forState:UIControlStateReserved];
        //[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_on"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [sender setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
}
```

All buttons background images are set to "settings_off". That way when I want to switch the settings I either set the buttons image to "settings_on" or NIL.

Problem is when I run the app, the buttons that has an image set to "settings_on" work fine (well, one problem is I need to click twice the first time to make the switch, but thats minor for now) but the buttons without an image set never switch. I have tried settings the images for the various states (selected, highlighted, normal), when I do this, then after the switch from on to off(nil), it won't switch back (as opposed to when being commented out). Im lost, any help appreciated thanks!

EDIT: Clearing all buttons from their backgroundImages, and only using "image" got it working; even though I still don't understand why my initial approach shouldn't be working. AFAIK the image view will overlay the background view...
Does anybody know why I have to click twice the first time to get the switch going?

Comment: Button's don't normally have an imageView property. Have you added one to your buttons?

Comment: @rdelmar Button's do in fact have an imageView property: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uibutton_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/imageView

Comment: The nil statement's wrong... Try if (sender.imageView.image == nil) instead. FYI though -- those two switchSettings methods and conditional statements are doing two completely different things... I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @LyndseyScott, Thanks for the correction; I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I tried everything for testing in frustration last night, I do see after waking up that it turned into a madness:) I have now updated my post with my INITIAL method only. (Sleep is not overrated O_o)

Comment: @awp2004 Are you trying to emulate a stateful button? If so, I can offer some suggestions. One approach is to use UIControlStateSelected to add or remove image from setImage, versus setBackgroundImage.

Comment: @DenVog It's not my question. I just edited it.

Comment: @DenVog And the OP, got it working after all, but just want to understand the issues with his/her original approach.

Comment: Indeed miss. After all all the code suggestions give me the same issues as I got before posting this question. Im still interested in  why I have to click twice to switch the setting initially (after that it switches like it should); I have to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below code?

```
- (IBAction)switchSetting:(UIButton *)sender {
if([sender backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_off"] ){
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Yes I have, I think theres some interference with background image and having an image. Please check my post edit

Answer (score 0):

You can check UIButton Image with sender.currentImage :

```
- (IBAction)switchSetting:(UIButton *)sender {

if ([sender.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_off"]]) 
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_on"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_off"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}

}
```

Hope this will help you in checking button current  image .

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `tag` value on button accordingly then after that you can check the condition using `switch` statement.